Possible to create PDF Attachment dynamically in SendGrid?
I'm trying to see if it is possible to create an email using SendGrid with a PDF attachment that utilising custom data...
For example, Customer A sees a PDF of Customer A related Data, Customer B sees a PDF of Customer B related data and so on.
I can create a PDF from an existing PDF, which I just find weird, and creating a PDF from a URL doesn't work as the PDF always comes out corrupted, so my only options at the moment are to make a PDF from an existing PDF.
Twilio/SendGrid documentation, StackOverflow and Google
Has anyone had experience with this and could offer some advice?

So in the end I used PDFKit to generate a PDF that I then attach to the SendGrid API request... here is a basic wireframe of what I am doing
require('dotenv').config(); // Have to use this as my local is being a d*ck
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const apiKey = `${process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY}`;
const fs = require('fs');
sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey);

//Create PDF Dynamically
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4'});
const filename = "customerData.pdf";

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)); // write to PDF

// add stuff to PDF here...
doc.font('Helvetica')
doc.fontSize(12);
doc.text('Hello world!')

// finalise the PDF and end the stream
doc.end();

let attachment = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString("base64");

const msg = {
  to: 'receipient@email.com',
  from: 'sender@email.com',
  subject: 'Attachment',
  html: '<p>Please find your PDF attached!</p>',
  attachments: [
    {
      content: attachment,
      filename: filename,
      type: "application/pdf",
      disposition: "attachment"
    }
  ]
};
(async () => {
  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg).then(() => console.log('send mail success'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body)
    }
  }
})();

Hopefully this will help someone else who is experiencing a similar problem
